# Creating a random URL in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, meteor, socket.io

I'm playing around with socket.io and would like to make it so that when someone visits my app, they start out at a random URL (site.com/52436) and that url is the url that they would share with someone else that initiates a room and allows them to chat with each other. My question is, is how do I make it so when they visit site.com, it goes to site.com/56443 and initiates a room with the same id?

Edit: I'm using the meteor framework.

Comment: I'm sure it's not. Maybe you could point me in the right direction with some resources so that I can figure it out.

Comment: as a task its not that difficult, if you implement some kind of authentication for users to join a room you could avoid abuse. Simply create a route `/room/:number` and work with socket.io to achieve the rest of functionality.

Comment: How do I make it so that when you visit the page, it starts out at site.com/435345 or site.com/room/354346 rather than site.com? That's my question, sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: When someone hits the route '/', you redirect them to `/xyzabc`. `res.redirect('/xyzabc')` But that is a bad way of solving this problem.

Comment: Well there wouldn't be anything on /xyzabc, so it would just 404, right? I have created a route `app.get('/:id', function() {console.log('creating room');});`  I just need it to start at /:id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example I had available (this is coffeescript).  It requires iron router and cookie, but your logic would generate it randomly instead.  It happens on client.

```
Meteor.startup ->

  auto = Cookie.get('autosubscribe')
  if auto
    Router.go 'publicScreen',
      _id: auto
```

I also suggest that the meteor framework has socket built into it, and that you may want to look at the chat example.  They hide a lot from you, which can be a good thing.